# Thoughts on storing a public SSH key in a Github repo?

Tags: github, ssh, public-key

Yo guys,

quite simple, maybe silly question.

I often need to give people my public key or, for example, re-import it when I get a new laptop or when re-installing the OS.

I was thinking of uploading it on a github public repo, as [there should be no problem in doing so](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/406/how-should-i-distribute-my-public-key), so that it would be uber-easy for me to retrieve it whenever I need it.

Thoughts? Any better alternative?

The driver for putting it on github is mainly the idea that they won't likely be down and I wont need to remember a random dropbox link.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there are two ways already to retrieve the public keys of a user.

Getting it via json through the API:

https://api.github.com/users/odino/keys

Or plain via web:

https://github.com/odino.keys